# Mod rewrite query param name

Tags: .htaccess

I need to rewrite URL article.php?id=x to index.php?p=x
I have tried doing it by this

```
RewriteRule ^article.php?id=(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA]
```

but it doesn't work, although this `RewriteRule ^article.php/(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA]` is working perfectly for article.php/x. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a `RewriteRule`, you need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable in a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ index.php?p=%1 [L]
```

Also, you **don't** want to use the `QSA` flag here, since that will append the query string that you *don't want*.